# is the verb "lie" in the sense of telling lies always stative?

Tags: present-tense, stative-verbs

I was watching *Lord of the Rings*, and in the scene where the ork said that Aragorn had fallen off the cliff, Legolas said: "you lie". Why did he say it in the present simple time?
Wouldn't the present progressive be more appropriate in that situation?

Comment: "Why did he **say** it in the present...?"  **did** is the tensed verb in that construction, and it partners with the bare infinitive, **say**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some writers use the simple present  in places where a contemporary native speaker would use the progressive in order to give the words of their characters a somewhat antique feel.  "You're lying" would sound too contemporary, too normal and "everyday".

Ngram isn't always a good indicator of spoken patterns, but you can see from [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=You+lie%2CYou%27re+lying&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CYou%20lie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CYou%20%27re%20lying%3B%2Cc0) that "You lie" spikes in the 17th century.

NOTE: There's a glitch with the apostrophe in that URL.  Search 1600-2000 for `You lie, You're lying`.